# Python plugins don't work on QGIS 2.14 for Scientific Linux 7

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7, linux, red-hat

I'm on Scientific Linux 7 and have been trying to install QGIS. According to the [instructions](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#rhel-centos-scientific-linux), I need to

```
sudo wget fedora.vitu.ch/EL/qgis.repo -P /etc/yum.repos.d/
sudo rpm --import http://fedora.vitu.ch/Fedora/RPM-GPG-Key-vitu
sudo yum update
sudo yum install qgis qgis-python qgis-grass qgis-mapserver
```

The first step fails with a 403, but running the final two steps anyway did work, as QGIS seems to be available in the epel repo.

Now when I run QGIS though, I get the error "No module named sip".

I've looked everywhere and the only installers/source for SIP are for python 3. Is it possible to install SIP on python 2.7? Is there a workaround to get QGIS plugins working?

Comment: On a simple search in the package repos using the command `# dnf search qgis`, I am getting all the packages required which are `qgis qgis-python`, `qgis-grass` & `qgis-mapserver`. Maybe my repository is enabled. Check yours by doing the same.

Comment: As I said above, I did run ```sudo yum install qgis qgis-python qgis-grass qgis-mapserver```.

Comment: I did have to skip qgis-grass though, as it requires libgeos-3.4.2. I have libgeos-3.5.0 installed, but apparently grass won't accept this.

Comment: Well, I've successfully installed that on my Fedora-26 machine. Which distro are you using?

Comment: Scientific Linux 7